# Put text on top of an image?

Tags: itext

I would need to insert images in a pdf and then put text on top of the image at certain coordinates.

Is this possible with iTextSharp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can.

The key is to set your `iTextSharp.text.Image` `Alignment` property to `iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING`.

[This page on mikesdotnetting.com](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images) has an example.

Comment: Could you explain it in more detail? I have a Image which represents the Background of the PDF. Now i would like to add text on this Background. How could i do this?